# Only some rules working on test environment, all work on live

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been updating my website that was made a few years ago. I recently moved from a windows test environment (worked perfectly fine for this purpose with no issues) to ubuntu 16.04. many years experience here. This is a really weird issue and I'm at a loss how to fix it.

I've shortened my htaccess for the purposes of just showing you what works and what doesn't.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]*)/? /admin.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(img)
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /media.php?i=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

So. On my windows test env and on live server, the top rule works perfectly fine, but on my new dev environment only the bottom rule seems to apply. If i try to request localhost/admin/short it will give me 404. If I request any url that doesn't start with 'admin', isn't requesting the img directory, and isn't a file that exists, the rewrite will send it to media.php like it should.

What should happen is localhost/admin/short ==> localhost/admin.php?p=short

and noo clue. I thought maybe it could be case sensitivity or something, but no all the php files are lowercase. Anyone have any ideas? Any info I can provide?

So I'm at a loss here. Among other things that don't work are

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

My intention: localhost/upload ==> localhost/upload.php

Could it be a file permissions issue? This is what it looks like:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data  10113 Nov 13 15:23 admin.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data   2796 Nov 13 14:07 index.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data   3664 Nov 13 11:49 media.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root     www-data    261 Dec 20 23:57 .htaccess
```

I found one answer that said:

> it turned out that the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` had
>   the `AllowOverride All`, but the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` also had
>   the same entry for our web `Directory` with `AllowOverwrite None`. So
>   be sure to check both places!

I changed it, but still not working.

Oddly, it works if I put my rewrite info in my apache2.conf
like so

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
RewriteEngine on
... etc ...
</Directory>
```

Comment: Just to be sure: Everything is running at the web root, and not in a subdirectory? Your provided rules seem to be working fine for me. That being said, using a PHP based router might be a good idea if you are rewriting your site.

Comment: if by 'web root' you mean /var/www/html, yes. The main page is /var/www/html/index.php

Comment: The last thing I changed before this spontaneously decided to work was explicitly tell apache2.conf to allowoverrides on /var/www/html (even though it says it in /var/www). I restarted, it worked. So I tried removing that, but it still works lol

Comment: Well, glad you got that working - my best guess otherwise was something to do with order - for example if your media rewrite occurred before your upload -> upload.php rewrite then it wouldn't work.

Comment: Well, I'm using the same htaccess as live, maybe `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` helped. In my conf I have `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews` and it doesn't work until I add that line on htaccess. Though I tried this before and it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I changed htaccess to reflect. Now it will only say `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Options Indexes FollowSymLinks`

Answer (score 0):

Your rules could be better:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [END]
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]*) admin.php?p=$1 [NS,QSA,DPI,END]
RewriteRule ^(?!img/)[^\.]+$ media.php?i=$0 [NS,QSA,DPI,END]
```